# C# Reflection get value from ICollection

Tags: c#, reflection, sqlexception

i'm struggling with a problem and I'm unable to find a solution.

In a certain moment of my code, a `SqlException` is thrown.

I have created a method using reflection to iterate through all the properties from any exception and perform some logic, but I'm having an issue with this one.

One of its members call `Errors`, that inherits from `SqlErrorCollection`. (According to MSDN documentation, the class definition is

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ListBindableAttribute(false)]
public sealed class SqlErrorCollection : ICollection,
```

The code I use to check if a property is a list doesn't work for this property:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)
    && typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)
    && prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
```

And when I will get it value using the code below

```
property.GetValue(myObject, null);
```

an TargetParameterCountException (Parameters count mismatch) is raised.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Why do you even need to use Reflection? What are you trying to achieve here? Explaining that will bring better answers rather than asking [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Which property is throwing the exception? My guess is that you're calling `GetValue` on an indexed property, and it's throwing that exception because you're passing `null` rather than an index parameter.

Comment: `SqlErrorCollection` is *non* generic, it uses the non-generic version of `ICollection`.

Comment: I'm using reflection to generate a xml string of the full exception. I already tried using XmlSerializer to achieve this, but according to other Stack Overflow questions, this isn't possible with the Exception class

Comment: All exception classes are serialize. You can use `BinarySerializer` to serialize it. if you want. Or you could simply loop the `SqlErrorCollection` if that's what you're after.

Comment: Sriram, this is exactly what I wanted first, loop the SqlErrorCollection, but I can't find a way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the insight provided by pmcoltrane, the Error property is an indexed property. The article [iterating through an indexed property (Reflection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268244/iterating-through-an-indexed-property-reflection) helped to solve my problem.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Looping through the errors in `SqlException` is very easy. if that's what you're after, here you go.

```
private string GenerateMessage(SqlException ex)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (SqlError error in ex.Errors)
    {
        builder.Append(error.ToString());
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a way to do this in a generic way using reflection, like exception.GetType().GetProperty("Error").GetValue(myObject, null)

Comment: @MarlonVidal What if Error property doesn't exist? Why are you complicating things?

Answer (score 1):

`prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType` check will return false, since SqlErrorsCollection is non-generic. As for second part of the problem - I was unable to reproduce this exception when getting property value. Following code executes without exceptions:

```
// create inner sql error collection instance through reflection
var sqlErrorCollCtor = typeof(SqlErrorCollection).GetConstructors(
  BindingFlags.Instance 
| BindingFlags.NonPublic 
| BindingFlags.NonPublic).FirstOrDefault();

var errorCollection = (SqlErrorCollection)sqlErrorCollCtor.Invoke(null);

// create sql exception instance through reflection
var sqlExceptionCtor = typeof(SqlException).GetConstructors(
  BindingFlags.Instance 
| BindingFlags.NonPublic 
| BindingFlags.NonPublic).FirstOrDefault();

var exception = sqlExceptionCtor.Invoke(
  new object[] { "Test", errorCollection, null, new Guid() });

// retrieve Errors property
var prop = exception.GetType().GetProperty("Errors");

if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)
    && typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) )
    // && prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
{
    var val = prop.GetValue(exception, null);
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Could it be that you are retrieving value from another object, not SqlException?